# MySQL match table column from another table for all table with same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have "users"

```
user_id usr_name email
1       john     john@yahoo.com
2       mike     mike@gmail.com 
3       tom      tom@hotmail.com
```

table "positions"

```
pod_id   pos_name      magic_id email
1        carpenter       22     mike@gmail.com 
2        driver          33
3        guard           44     john@yahoo.com
4        cleaner         55     tom@hotmail.com
5        accountant      66
```

now in table users i create column "magic_id"

is there way to add it from table positions with single query?

e.g.

```
UPDATE users 
   LEFT JOIN positions on positions.email = users.email
      SET users.magic_id = positions.magic_id
```

will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, as can be seen at this SQLFiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431a9/1

```
UPDATE users 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON 
        positions.email = users.email
SET 
    users.magic_id = positions.magic_id;
```

Comment: I modified your query slightly, but your original version works fine too.

Comment: never modify actual query... Other folks don't get where he is wrong... please keep original question as it is...

Comment: He probably means he modified it in his answer...

Thanks that works indeed, i did not know you can refer to positions.magic_id just by typing it